# how to access json array in FutureBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have created my model class and through `Dio` I store and display the server information in my class but my problem is that I want to access the `jsonarray` of chart fields json object and display them in FutureBuilder app response.

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"arthor",
      "chart":[
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256523"
         },
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256522"
         },
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256525"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My class model:

```dart
class Chart {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  List<Chart>? chart;
  Chart({this.id, this.name, this.chart});
  Chart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    if (json['chart'] != null) {
      chart = <Chart>[];
      json['chart'].forEach((v) {
        chart!.add(new Chart.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    if (this.chart != null) {
      data['chart'] = this.chart!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Chart {
  String? a;
  String? b;
  String? c;
  Chart({this.a, this.b, this.c});
  Chart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    a = json['a'];
    b = json['b'];
    c = json['c'];
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['a'] = this.a;
    data['b'] = this.b;
    data['c'] = this.c;
    return data;
  }

  static List<Chart> fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonlList) {
    return jsonlList
        .map((e) => Chart.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

My Future method API:

```dart
Future<List<Chart>> getCategory() async {
  String link = "xxxxxxx";
  var response = await Dio().get(link + id.toString());
  return Rate.fromJsonList(response.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artin Jan, here is an example of your need:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Chart>>(
  future: getCategory(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final chartList = snapshot.data![0].chart!;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: chartList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final chart = chartList[index];
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text(chart.a!),
              Text(chart.b!),
              Text(chart.c!),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
);
```

if it didn't help please let me know and share more detail.

EDIT:

According to your Map :

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"arthor",
      "chart":[
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256523"
         },
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256522"
         },
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256525"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

It won't be correct if you say `snapshot.data![index].chart!` because `snapshot.data![0].chart!` is the only item of `snapshot.data`
and you don't have another items. now final `chartList = snapshot.data![0].chart!` is

```
[
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256523"
         },
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256522"
         },
         {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256525"
         }
      ]
```

and

```
 chartList[0] => is => {
                "a":"allow",
                "b":"23",
                "c":"256523"
             }


 chartList[1] => is => {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256522"
         }



chartList[2] => is => {
            "a":"allow",
            "b":"23",
            "c":"256525"
         }
```

If you use the recommended code with the map structure that you've provided, you won't have any problem.

happy coding...

Comment: `final chartList = snapshot.data![index].chart!;
final chart = chartList[index];
print(chart.chTimestamp!);`

Thank you, the problem I have now is that it only displays the first data of the arraylist-chart

Comment: `if (snapshot.hasData) {
final chartList = snapshot.data![0].chart!;
return ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
final chart = chartList[index];
var a = chart.a.toString();
var b = a + " - " + chart.b.toString();
print(b);`
The problem now is that it only displays the item from the chart list when there are more !

Comment: I did not understand what do you exactly need?

Comment: I want to store the data of field "a" in arraylist "chart" in a list and display it in my chart

Comment: do you have discord(my id => Eric J#0036)? if you don't tell me to connect in meet to see what is your exact problem.

Comment: Discord id not found bro
pls check 
my id 
`ah.maleki99#1151`

Answer (score 0):

```
FutureBuilder<List<Chart>>(future:getCategory(),builder((context,snapshot){
if(snapshot.hasData){
// your data has arrived, show UI accordingly
}
else if (snapshot.hasError){
//error
}
else {
//loading
}
});
```

Comment: bro how to show chart json array in ui ?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?